# Couldn't installl NtopNG on Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Tags: networking

I tried to install NtopNg on Ubuntu 18.04. Got in the below error.

```
apt-get install pfring-dkms nprobe ntopng n2disk cento -y
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    cento is already the newest version (1.11.191119-528).
    n2disk is already the newest version (3.3.191119-5173).
    nprobe is already the newest version (8.7.191119-6669).
    pfring-dkms is already the newest version (7.5.0).
    The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
      libndpi5
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      ntopng
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/9,043 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 47.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    (Reading database ... 74204 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../ntopng_3.9.191119-8152_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking ntopng (3.9.191119-8152) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ntopng_3.9.191119-8152_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css', which is also in package ntopng-data 3.2+dfsg1-1
    dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/ntopng_3.9.191119-8152_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `apt-update`

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt remove ntopng-data` then try again.  You've got conflicting packages trying to write to the same file, which is a Bad Thing.